# Matlab / Octave - trouble getting started with functions, is there a function main equivalent?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to get started with Matlab / Octave and having a difficult time figuring how to organize a program into functions.  Currently I'm trying to write a simple program that adds two numbers together and displays the result, with the adding being done by a function.  I would have figured this would have worked:

```
% test.m

close all;
clear all;

num1 = 2;
num2 = 2;

result = myAdd(num1, num2);

disp(result);          % this should display 4 ??

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
function retval = myAdd(var1, var2)
  retval = var1 + var2;
end
```

Running the above with Octave 4.0.0, I get the following errors:

```
error: 'myAdd' undefined near line 7 column 10
error: called from
    test at line 7 column 8
```

I have tried also putting the function first and the test part second, and also putting the function in a separate file and having a main.m file in the same directory call the myAdd function, all result in errors.

So here are my questions:

-Does Matlab / Octave have a main equivalent ??

-How does the interpreter know where to start?  Does it automatically go to the first line in the program, or is there a certain function name you can use to make it start with that function as function main() is in C/C++ ??

-In a Python program of significant size, my usual practice is to organize things as follows:

```
# some_python_program.py

import abc
import xyz

###################################################################################################
def main():

    # stuff to get program started here

# end main

###################################################################################################
def function1():

    # specific function here

# end function

###################################################################################################
def function2():

    # specific function here

# end function

###################################################################################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Is there a way to do the equivalent in Matlab/Octave ??

If somebody could provide some direction as to a main equivalent and/or how to organize functions in Matlab/Octave please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matlab/Octave can be a bit confusing in this way if you're coming from a language like python. In order to define a function (without using anonymous functions), you need to create a separate file with the name of that function, which can then be called using the command line.

For example, you would like to create a function called `myadd`. You should create a file named `myadd.m` whose contents will be:

```
function out = myadd(a,b)
    out = a+b;
end
```

Then, as long as your file is on your path (save it to your MATLAB folder or put it in your current working directory), you can call it from the Command Window as follows:

```
>> myadd(5,6)

ans =

     11
```

Only one function will be made publicly available per file (the one whose name matches the file name). However, you can still define multiple functions per file if you plan to use only that function. For example, if you have a file named `foo.m`, you can do the following:

```
function out = foo(a,b)
    out = fun(a,b);
end

function out = fun(a,b)
    out = a * b;
end
```

This will allow you to call `foo(5,6)` from the Command Window, but `fun(5,6)` will result in an error: `Undefined function or variable 'fun'`.

Read more about [local functions](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html) and [nested functions](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html).

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Yes, very helpful thanks.  I did the following based on your recommendation and it worked:

1) made a file "myAdd.m", including the add function above

2) chose "Command Window" in Octave and entered "myAdd(2, 2)" at the prompt and it showed 4 (as it should)

3) I created a file in the same directory with only 2 lines, 1st "result = myAdd(2, 2);", then "disp(result);" and switching back to the prompt it again showed 4 as it should.

Final follow-up question: Is there a way to include test code for a function in the same file as the function?

Comment: I admittedly don't know very much about MATLAB's [unit test framework](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-unit-test-framework.html), so I'm unsure. I typically write additional functions (normally named `test_$FUNCTION_NAME`, and run those instead.